# how to set size to texture_size in python

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So this is the .kv code:

```
Button:
    id:last_message_2
    text:''
    font_size:18
    background_normal:'textures/message.png'
    size_hint_x:None
    size: self.texture_size
    pos_hint:{'right': 1}
    padding:(9, 0)
    opacity:0
    on_release: root.onClick("send_rcnt2")
```

and what i want to do is make a custom button widget like this:

```
class MessageBubble(Button):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(MessageBubble, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.text = "Hello World"
        self.font_size = 18
        self.background_normal = "textures/message.png"
        self.size_hint_x = None
        self.size = self.texture_size
        self.pos_hint = {'right': 1}
        self.padding = (9, 0)
        self.opacity = 0
```

and have only this left in the .kv file:

```
MessageBubble:
    id:last_message_1
    on_release: root.onClick("send_rcnt1")
```

but when i run the code i get a very small button with text out off bound
and when i debugged i got to know that `texture_size` was not updating dynamically

What can i do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `size` in the kv rule for MessageBubble, because it needs to be updated later when self.texture_size changes. You can also do this manually by creating bindings in python.

Comment: You say it's not possible inside the init class?

Comment: You can create bindings inside the `__init__`, but the texture_size isn't set to its final value at that point.

Comment: Ok then I should write that in kv file thanks!